# Filters in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-filters

I am facing a task to add a dependent jar application to an existing one. The existing one does not use to much of locale benefits and so on, but my new one should.

So like I have now: `localhost:8080/old-app`
I want to have also: `localhost:8080/[en|fr|...]/new-module`

Could anyone point me the direction, because even if I think I get the idea of filters, filter-mapping, I cannot manage to solve it.

I would like to keep the old one and also have access to the new one.

Comment: do you want to auto-redirect from /old-app to /new-app? Or you want to make the old app available on a new URL pattern?

Comment: I'm afraid this question doesn't make any sense to me, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Deploy `new-module` as `ROOT.war` (or set `path` in `/META-INF/context.xml` to `/`). Use [Tuckey's `URLRewriteFilter`](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) to rewrite specific URL's and transform the language part to a request parameter so that it's available by `request.getParameter()`. It's much similar to Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`.

An alternative to `URLRewriteFilter` is to homegrow a custom filter which does like the following in `doFilter()` method.

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
if (uri.matches("^/\\w{2}(/.*)?$")) {
    request.setAttribute("language", uri.substring(1, 3));
    request.getRequestDispatcher(uri.substring(3)).forward(request, response);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Map this on an `url-pattern` of `/*`. The language will be available by `request.getAttribute("language")` on the forwarded resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the applications name as context root e.g. localhost:8080/appname but under / directly you have to put it into the `tomcat/webapps/ROOT` folder. To get more sophisticated URL mappings working have a look at http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Comment: PrettyFaces is for JSF webapps only. Where did you read that OP is using JSF?